# How do I get selected text from a non-editable textbox in silverlight for wp7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm want to have a textbox with text that the user can select but not edit, and I want to perform some operations on that text.

I create a textbox and set IsReadOnly="True". When I then tap on some text, i see it being highlighted, but when the SelectionChanged event is triggered, textBox1.SelectedText is empty.

When IsReadOnly="False", it works, but the keyboard pops up, which I don't want.
Does anyone know how to achieve what I want? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having tried this out myself (and confirmed what you've been seeing) I would personally say this was a bug, in which case you should report it on the [App Hub forums](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/98.aspx). The documentation for `TextBox.IsReadOnly` property states: "If the text box is read-only, no user input or edits are allowed, but programmatic changes can be made. The user can still select text, and the cursor still appears. The KeyUp and KeyDown events are marked as handled." but I don't see why you shouldn't be able get the SelectedText (or SelectionStart and SelectionLength, which are also always 0 for a read-only TextBox).

In terms of a workaround, I think you'd need to create a custom TextBox template that didn't provide an editable interface, while still supporting selection, and not set IsReadOnly to false so that the SelectedText, SelectionStart, and SelectionLength properties remain valid. might be a tall order though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the Text property of a TextBox when it is readonly, you have to set it as an attribute. Something like this TextBoxName.Attributes.Add("value", "SomeText");

Comment: I'm not trying to change the text in the textbox, I want to know what text the user has selected. It works when I create it using the Silverlight-not-for-windows-phone

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. See if this link helps you. It talks about how you can set the SelectionStart property of a Readonly TextBox http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've run into exactly the same issue, whenever the SelectionChanged event fires my ReadOnly textbox would report .SelectionStart & .SelectionLength as 0.

Following up on Derek's suggestion about templating, I had poke around the default control template for the Textbox. The root of the problem seems to be that the template uses two different xaml elements internally, one read-write & the other read-only. I suspect what is happening is that the read-only element, when made visible by IsReadOnly=True, fires SelectionChanged events but the Textbox selection properties only ever report the selection state of the read-write element.

I've knocked up a stripped down control template that just has a single content presenter and does away with any styling of the control based on visual states which does the trick & even though IsReadOnly is set True reports .SelectionStart & .SelectionLength correctly.

You can apply it either by styling or directly setting the Textbox's .Template property.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
    <Grid
        Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
        Background="Transparent">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <Border
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            Margin="0">
            <ContentControl 
                x:Name="ContentElement" 
                BorderThickness="0" 
                Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxInnerMargin}" 
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```